# How to SUM the value from an input

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sum

I have an input form where I introduce a number. When I hit submit button, I want the number I entered in the input, to SUM with the current value from a column. 
Do I need to use UPDATE and SUM in the same query?

Thank you very much for your time. :)

Comment: `update yourtable set yourfield = yourfield + $_POST['enterednumber']`, if you're feeling like living dangerously...

Comment: Thank you. This one I used and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `sum`, just the `+` operator:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    mycolumn = mycolumn + :input
WHERE  id = :id
```

Comment: Thank you. I used `$` instead of `:` and worked perfectly. :)